# Default boolean setting in DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto

I want to define default false for boolean but it seems still true as default on swagger.

How could I define this to see false as default.

Swagger request :

```
{
  "transferList": [
    {
      "reverseFlag": true,
      "transactionId": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Dto class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransferDto {

    private Long transactionId;
    private Boolean reverseFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: You need to look for specific Swagger annotation in the code which sets this value to `true` by default.

Answer (score 0):

This way is not enough.

You can try this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransferDto {
    private Long transactionId;
    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean reverseFlag = false;
}
```